# I am using System.Diagnostics.Process to run the sqlite special command but only half of the commands get executed

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=C:\sqlite\test.db; Version=3; FailIfMissing=True; Foreign Keys=True;";

SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);          
conn.Open();

string batFilePath = @"D:\mockforbat.bat";

if (!File.Exists(batFilePath))
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(batFilePath))
    {
        fs.Close();
    }
}

using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(batFilePath))
{
    sw.WriteLine(@"C:");
    sw.WriteLine(@"cd\");
    sw.WriteLine(@"cd sqlite");
    sw.WriteLine(@"sqlite3 test.db");
    sw.WriteLine(@".mode csv");
    sw.WriteLine(@".import D:/Ashif/SQLITE/Bulk.csv excelUpload"); 
}

Process process = Process.Start(batFilePath);
process.WaitForExit();
```

When I execute this command, it will execute only up to the "sqlite3 test.db" line, and the other commands are not executed.

The output I get after executing of the code:

[image: Output after executing the code]

Comment: Are those `.mode csv` and `.import ....` really *arguments* for the `sqlite3` command? Then I believe you need to specify those **on the same line** (even if it gets quite long) - not on separate lines.

Comment: both are the commands for sqlite3 .And they are two different command we can't write on the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't explicitly ask a question, so I assume the question is "how can I call the sqlite command line from my program with the relevant arguments?"

The sqlite3 command line interface is interactive by default, but you probably don't want that when using it as part of a script/automated execution.

The [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sqlite3) shows a `-init file` argument that should be more appropriate for what you want to achieve.

Try to add your meta-commands (`.mode csv`, `.import x`...) in a separate `myFile`, and execute `sqlite3 -init myFile` and it should work.

---

Aside from this main question, I see potential problems with your code:

You are opening a connection to a database with `new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);` but you are never using this connection. Instead, you are connecting again to your database by executing the `sqlite3 test.db` in your bat file.

if you are using `Process.Start()` you don't need a bat file, you can directly call `sqlite3` with the required arguments. (Though you will probably need the full path of `sqlite3` for this to work)

To sum up, you could use something like that (untested, adapt as needed):

```cs
            var sqliteScriptPath = @"D:\myScript.txt";
            var scriptContent = @"
.mode csv
.open test.db
.import D:/Ashif/SQLITE/Bulk.csv excelUpload";

            File.WriteAllText(sqliteScriptPath, scriptContent);

            Environment.CurrentDirectory = @"C:\sqlite"; // If you use relative paths somewhere in your command you will need something like that
            // You can also create a ProcessStartInfo instance, and set its WorkingDirectory property before giving it to Process.Start()

            Process process = Process.Start("sqlite3", $"-init {sqliteScriptPath}");
            process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Happy to help! If you feel like this answer solved your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer (green check-mark). Thanks you :)